# Azure Devops API - How to create and auto-complete a pull request from a UNC path

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api

In this situation, devs will drop their code off in a central fileshare when it's ready to enter the pipeline.

I'm currently attempting to work with the Azure Devops API for "Pull Request - Create" to create and complete a pull request from a UNC Path to an empty Azure Devops GIT repo.

[API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

I am struggling with how to setup the body to accomplish this.

The path that I am trying to pull from would be:

`\\10.10.10.10\fileshare\code\application`.

The body that I am currently trying to create looks like:

```
{
  "remoteUrl": "file://\10.10.10.10\fileshare\code\application",
  "sourceRefName": "origin/master",
  "targetRefName": "master",
  "title": "Automatic Update",
  "description": "Automatically updating the repo",
  "status": "completed"
}
```

Does anyone know if this is even possible? If so, I would greatly appreciate any nudges in the right direction.

Comment: Do you try to create a PR to git repo that exist only in your file share?

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `remoteUrl` is the git repo url. in fact you not need it in the body because in the url you have the repo id. so how the file share is connected to the `remoteUrl`?

Comment: Why would people put their code in a file share? Teach them to use Git. Have them commit to a repository.

Comment: To clarify, there is a git repo at the UNC file share location. Due to technical restraints, I am not able to push into TFS and need to pull it from the fileshare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create and auto-complete a pull request from a UNC path

Afraid to say that No, it could not be possible to achieve. The `remoteUrl` in request body means the Url of the git repos, like the `https://Merlin@dev.azure.com/Merlin/UnitTest/_git/dotnet-project`.

This is the sample I created:

[image]

You can see that the value of `remoteUrl` is the **Url of repos in Azure Devops**, this is **fixed** after your repos exists in the org and could not be changed.

So, agree with Shayki and Daniel. Please let your colleague commit it to repository.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Specifically, is it possible to use the API to pull from a git repo outside of azure Devops (i.e. a UNC fileshare)? And is it possible to complete the pull request via the same API call? Or is a second (or multiple) calls required? If so, what does this look like? Thanks!

Comment: No, the `remoteUrl` must be the repos git url which the `repository id` exists. This means since `repository id` can only exist depend on the Azure Devops, the url must be the git url of repos.

Comment: So... is there a different API available that can be used to import a remote git repo from outside of Azure Devops into Azure Devops?

Comment: Of course it has. But it's the client api. See this doc and samples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops

Comment: As what see from the sample. I'd better recommend import with git command instead of with API.

Comment: Hey Merlin. I'm definitely open to that, but thought that API would be the only method. What would it look like to setup a git pull to one of the Azure Devops repos? I'm assuming that I could do that from within a script within a pipeline?

Comment: @nuprap Do you mean where these api script could exist?

Comment: You mentioned that "I'd better recommend import with git command instead of with API." I'm curious if there's an example of that somewhere, I have never used git cli to update built-in Azure Devops repos through git pull.

Comment: Aha, there has several methods to run git command. If you want to try with local cli, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/git?view=vsts-cli-latest). In addition, the git command can also executed in the command line task of pipeline,   check the [sample showed in doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: Hi, @nuprap how the things going now? Feel free to let us know the latest status thus we can help you further.

Comment: Hey @Merlin Liang - MSFT ... Thanks for the info, while it didn't give me the complete solution for my issue, I would not have been able to get to my conclusion without your help. I got vague errors (fatal remote end hung up unexpectedly) from a failing "git push" in my pipeline... turns out that this error can be many things, including post buffer issues and also auth issues. I ended up troubleshooting and discovering that authenticating with the system access token got by this issue. Thanks! ```push -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" push -u origin --all```

Comment: @nuprap You are so welcome! My pleasure to help you. To help other SO users get completed solution from this issue, I will update my answer with more details from you and our comments when I back to office:-)